# How to get the cursor to change to the hand when hovering a <button> tag

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

When viewing my site, the cursor only changes to the gloved hand for `<a>` tags, not `<button>` tags. Is there a reason for this?

Here is my code (the button tags have an id of #more in css3).

```
 #more {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: There are [reasons](https://medium.com/simple-human/buttons-shouldnt-have-a-hand-cursor-b11e99ca374b) for that. And history if you follow links. Modifying current default cursor styles set by vendors isn't necessary (if you design well your buttons and use the correct element, either a or submit or button)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

see: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

so you need to add: `cursor:pointer;`

In your case use:

```
#more {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

This will apply the curser to the element with the ID "more" (can be only used once). So in your HTML use

```
<input type="button" id="more" />
```

If you want to apply this to more than one button then you have more than one possibility:

**using CLASS**

```
.more {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

and in your HTML use

```
<input type="button" class="more" value="first" />
<input type="button" class="more" value="second" />
```

or **apply to a html context**:

```
input[type=button] {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

and in your HTML use

```
<input type="button" value="first" />
<input type="button" value="second" />
```

Comment: Link in answer seems dead.

Comment: I think the link should be https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Eigenschaften/Benutzeroberfl%C3%A4che/cursor, but I am not sure. Maybe @Thomas can help?

Comment: The selector for all selecting button input elements (`input[type=text]`) is incorrect. This should be: `input[type=button]`.

Answer (score 32):

Just add this style:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

The reason it's not happening by default is because most browsers reserve the pointer for links only (and maybe a couple other things I'm forgetting, but typically not `<button>`s).

More on the `cursor` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor

I usually apply this to `<button>` and `<label>` by default.

**NOTE**: I just caught this:

> the button tags have an id of `#more`

It's very important that each element has it's own unique `id`, you cannot have duplicates. Use the `class` attribute instead, and change your selector from `#more` to `.more`. This is actually quite a common mistake that is the cause of many problems and questions asked here. The earlier you learn how to use `id`, the better.

Comment: As a complete HTML/css noob, had to to see Aashish answer below to understand where to put cursor: pointer

Comment: Thanks for actually explaining why it's not added by default. Makes for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 10):

All u need is just use one of the attribute of CSS , which is---->

cursor:pointer

just use this property in css , no matter its inline or internal or external

for example(for inline css)

```
<form>
<input type="submit" style= "cursor:pointer" value="Button" name="Button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 #more {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```